# Exclude click event based on condition?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set conditions on a jQuery event. I have an input element and a div. I want to detect a click anywhere on the page and to execute that method but only if the click is not on the input or div.

Comment: So are you saying you want to be able to call a function anytime a user clicks on the page and it's not on the input or div?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the jQuery click() or live() functions and then check the target of the click event using the jQuery is() function.

1. bind click event on document
2. if the target is not input or div continue

.

```
$(document.body).click(function(e) {
  if( !$(e.target).is("input, div") ) {
    console.log("Run function because image or div were not clicked!");
  }
});
```

Example webpage => http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/forums/stack-overflow/example-document-click-exclusion.html

Example firebug output after clicking around on example page

[image]

Comment: @Mike No need to bubble it up to the document node. The BODY element is enough.

Comment: @codemonkey, glad that worked for you. Good luck on your project.

Comment: @Mike Use `$(document.body)` or `$("body")` - the first one is better.

Comment: @Šime, interesting. Why do you say that $(document.body) is better than $("body") ?

Comment: @Mike `document.body` is a built-in reference. It is created as soon as the page is rendered and it exists at all times. On the other hand, `"body"` is a selector. `$("body")` will make use of the jQuery's selector engine which will make a query based on the selector. Like all queries, it consumes time and processing power.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work.

```
$('body').click(function(event){ // body click
    var $target = $(event.target); // click target
    if($target.is('#mydiv, #myinput')) { // click target is div or input
        $target.click(); // click div or input
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically assign a click handler to the body of the page, then test the target Element of the event to see if the id of that target element matches your div or your input.

```
$("body").click(function(evt) {
  var targetElementId = evt.target.id;

  if (!(targetElementId  == "yourDivID" || targetElementId == "yourinputId"))
  {
    // your event code here.
  }
});
```

Comment: use $(event.target) as it is normalized by jquery event object. http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: You don't have to normalize the event object. jQuery does that for you.

Comment: Also, retrieve the id attribute like so: `foo.id`, not so: `$(foo).attr("id")`. The later is just an overkill in this case.

Comment: Also, I just figured that there already exists a built-in reference to the BODY element - `document.body`. Therefore, there is no need to use the selector engine to get it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = $("#yourInput")[0];
var div = $("#yourDiv")[0];

$(document.body).click(function(e) {
   switch ( e.target ) {
       case input: case div: return;
   }
   yourMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Example to exclude specific elements using a wildcard:

```
$("#mydiv li").click(function(e){

        var Target = new String(e.target.id);

        // prevent action when a element with id containing 'img_' is clicked
        if( !Target.match(/img_/ )) {
            // do something
        }

});
```