# window resize function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu and i want its dropdown to be accessible with hover when window width is >= 767px and accessible with click event when the window width is < 767px.

Its working only when i refresh the page, otherwise only hover event is working.

JQUERY

```
(function ($) {

    'use strict';

    function getWindowWidth() {
        var windowWidth = 0;
        if (typeof(window.innerWidth) === 'number') {
            windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        }
        else {
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
                windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            }
            else {
                if (document.body && document.body.clientWidth) {
                    windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(windowWidth);
        return windowWidth;
    }

    function widthStatement() {
        if (getWindowWidth() >= 767) {
            $('.menu > ul > li').on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, false).show();
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, false).hide();
                }
            });
        } else if (getWindowWidth() < 767) {
            $('.menu > ul > li').click(function () {
                $(this).children('ul').stop(true, false).toggle();
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(getWindowWidth, widthStatement);
    $(window).on('resize', widthStatement);

}($));
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}

.menu:before, .menu:after {
    display: table;
    content: ' ';
}

.menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul > li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul > li:hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

.menu ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em 2.5em;
    color: #444;
}

.menu ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

.menu ul > li > ul > li {
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 25%;
}

.menu ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #444;
}

.menu ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.menu ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: .5em 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: .9em;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">School</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Lidership</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Research</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate research</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters research</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Funding</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">School</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Lidership</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Empty sub</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

demo: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/yJVNMq

Comment: why not use css media queries to target the tow different width targets?

Comment: shouldnt it work this way to..

Comment: you could get this to work, but its considered a best practice to  avoid javascript for layout and use css when possible. In case you insist on using js, what is not working for you?  is the event handler being called?

Comment: It is, i loged and it returns width

Comment: It looks to me that you need to use .off() before the .on so that the previous attached event handler is removed.  I think this is going to put you on the right path but you still have an issue where when you click on a menu item that is a link you are going to that link so 'click' event on the menu might not be ideal.

Comment: @orangeh0g Would you write me an example of usage on and off at same time?

Comment: $('.menu > ul > li').off().on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, false).show();
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, false).hide();
                }
            });

Comment: @orangeh0g dropdown is still triggered only on hover when i put .off()

Comment: you have to do that to both attached event handlers.

Comment: @orangeh0g thanks dude, this works, and you did not question my logic, you give me simple answer. Thank you sir! Could you explain me why do i nedd .off().on() ?

Comment: You are attaching multiple event handlers to the same item.  This simply cleans up what was there before and allows you to only have one event handler attached at any given time.  This solves your issue but I would read up on it because there maybe better ways of doing it. Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with the way you're using .ready(). Anyway, you don't need to call getWindowWidth() when the document is ready, because your widthStatement() does it for you. Simply remove that and you're away:

```
$(document).ready(widthStatement);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWpXOp

Comment: this is now working. so more than 767px the dropdown goes on hover and below it goes on click. Your solution only goes on hover its not on click below 767

Comment: OK, so now I'm looking at the rest of the code it's clear your logic is not quite right. Basically, you need to include logic operators inside your element bindings. If you need more help figuring this out I'd suggest posting a new question as it's now beyond the scope of your original one. You can use something like this as your starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325790/exclude-click-event-based-on-condition

Comment: thanks for everything, i want this logic to work and its fixed, you can look in comments of my question what was the problem :)

Comment: You're welcome - as @orangeh0g mentions, his suggested code works but is not necessarily the "right" way to do things.

Comment: Besides not using mediqueries as triggers, what would you change? :)

Comment: so if statement must be questioned inside mouse event? Whats the benefit of that? performance or other? Great working solution btw

Comment: Putting your logic operators inside you binding: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxoQxL. Using this method you can also remove calling the function every time the window is resized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115212/discussion-between-ian-and-riogrande).